# Making closures type-stable dependent on the captured variable

Tags: function, julia, type-stability

For the function

```
function function_maker(N)
    if N == 1
        x = 1.0
    else
        x = 1
    end
    f(y) = x+y
end
```

I want the output of this to not be type-stable, but I want it to generate an `f` that is type-stable, i.e. uses the type of `x` determined by the value of `N` to generate a function dependent on `N`. Basically, I want the functions that come out of this to be performant, but the `function_maker` itself doesn't need to be performant because it's only used in the global scope or above a function barrier.

```
f = function_maker(1)
@code_warntype f(1)

Variables:
  #self#::#f#9
  y::Int64

Body:
  begin 
      return ((Core.getfield)((Core.getfield)(#self#::#f#9, :x)::ANY, :contents)::ANY + y::Int64)::ANY
  end::ANY
```

This doesn't happen by default. I tried `f(y) = x::typeof(x)+y` but that didn't work either. Is there a simple way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's:

```
julia> function function_maker2(N)
           if N == 1
               let x = 1.0
                   return f(y) = x + y
               end
           else
               let x = 1
                   return f(y) = x + y
               end
           end
       end
function_maker2 (generic function with 1 method)

julia> f2 = function_maker2(1)
(::f) (generic function with 1 method)

julia> @code_warntype f2(1)
Variables:
  #self#::#f#5{Float64}
  y::Int64

Body:
  begin 
      return (Base.add_float)((Core.getfield)(#self#::#f#5{Float64}, :x)::Float64, (Base.sitofp)(Float64, y::Int64)::Float64)::Float64
  end::Float64
```

This version separates the `x` in each branch inside `let` blocks. Otherwise the compiler seems to get confused.

Comment: It is interesting! Changing variable (x and xx) doesn't help: `function function_maker3(N) N == 1 && begin x = 1.;return y -> x + y end || begin xx=1; return y -> xx + y end end`. But replacing only the first one(!) `begin` with `let` works.  And replacing only the second one doesn't work.

Comment: Really cool answer! This is definitely a trick I'll have to keep in mind.

Comment: @Liso What you describe is interesting. To get the two variable name function to return type-stable `f`, I needed to add `local x::Float64, xx::Int64` before the conditional - presumably, so the compiler doesn't have uncertainty regarding the types of a local variable in an untaken conditional path. As for the `let` asymmetry between the first and second, have you tested the stability of `f` returned with both `function_maker(1)` and `function_maker(2)`? Perhaps the `let` branches are stable and the other branch not.

Comment: @DanGetz you are right! Sorry I was too quick... :/ I changed parameters in wrong places (resp. `function_maker(1)` <-> `function_maker(1.)` - which is useless). So changing `begin` to let is working expectable. I am not sure what am I doing wrong with local, but this doesn't work for me: `function function_maker3(N) local x::Float64, xx::Int64; N == 1 && begin x = 1.;return y -> x + y end || begin xx=1; return y -> xx + y end end;f2 = function_maker3(1);@code_warntype f2(1)`

Comment: @Liso It works for me, in that, it gives a type-stable `f2(1)`. Using `Julia Version 0.6.2-pre.3`

Comment: If I copy+paste code from my previous comment then `0.6.1` shows me 2times `::Any` and `0.7.0-DEV.2495` shows me 4times `::Any` and one time `::Core.box`...

Comment: @Liso You are right. Didn't notice the Any-s. Seems any assignment within the `if` brings the Any-s back. The only solution I found is to preassign `x = 1.0 ; xx = 1` outside the conditional